# Remove switch provisioning from individual switches

Tags: cisco, switch, stacking

I've been given two switches to work on, which separately have been used in a stack previously. One switch for one stack, and one switch for another st.ack in a different building. So they're not related.

**First switch**

```
switch 1 provisioning
```

**Second switch**

```
switch 2 provisioning
```

As these switches are not related to eachother from a previous stack, how I do remove the switch provisioning for each switch? If I were to attempt to remove the setting, it comes to back to say that it can't be done whilst the switch is present.

The first switch appears to be a master, with the other switch being the slave. Is there a config file that stores the settings for this? I've cleared the startup-configuration but this still remains.

Would I have to connect them both with stacking cables to create a stack first before I can deactivate the setting? These switches will be used individually in the future, so this is why I want the stack removed altogether.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: In general, clearing the startup-config nukes 99% of things, however there are some things that live outside the config. "erase nvram:" will totally remove all stored configuration information.

Comment: I beleive I tried that before, or maybe I just did **erase startup-configuration**. I'll try that and see if I can clear the full config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to un-provision the removed switch(es) and renumber the current one to be the 1st switch.

Your two switches are now standalone switches. In fact, each of them has turned into a single-switch stack and been acting a role of Active/Master.

To verfiy all previously-provisioned switches and their numbers, issue the commands `show run | i provision` and `show switch`.

Below are the sample outputs on a standalone switch which was the *2nd switch* of an old two-switch stack (after being broken into two single devices):

```
#show run | i provision
switch 1 provision ws-c2960x-48lps-l
switch 2 provision ws-c2960x-48lps-l

#show switch
Mac persistency wait time: Indefinite
                                             H/W   Current
Switch#   Role    Mac Address     Priority Version  State
------------------------------------------------------------
 1       Member   0000.0000.0000     0      0       Provisioned
*2       Active   aaaa.bbbb.cccc     15     A0      Ready
```

Now, the configuration of already-removed switch (*1st switch*) is still alive on this 2nd switch. You need to unprovision 1st switch, renumber the 2nd switch and reload the switch so it would remove the configuration of already-removed switch and become 1st switch (choose 'Yes' for all questions and save the configuration before reloading it).

```
    (config)#no switch 1 provision ws-c2960x-48lps-l
    (config)#end
    #switch 2 renumber 1
    #wr
    #reload
```

I hope it is helpful and answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to include this info. This would be very useful usually, but the problem I have is the related switch for each switch I have are no longer on-site use due to failures. So I don't have access to the other switches to unprovision the pair. That's the biggest issue I have, and I take it that I can't unprovision these unless I have the other provisioned switch connected to it?

Comment: @BabyPython No, this works with those seperate switches you have left after the break. You do not have to connect them back to unprovision. In my example above, I used to have two switches stacked together. Later when they were splited up into two seperate (single) one, I applied steps above to unprovision and renumber each of them.

Comment: Ok I'll see if that works. Once this is successful, will the switch provisioning line be removed from the config?

Comment: @BabyPython yes, it will.

Comment: No Luck unfortunately. I renumbered it and it came back as switch 1 and switch 2 when it reloaded, so I've got 2 entries now. I then did a `no switch 2 provision` and reloaded, and this takes me back to having one switch config again. I don't understand why this isn't working for me. It's pretty frustrating.

Comment: @BabyPython Let us discuss more [in this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66368/discussion-btw-hung-tran-and-babypython)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the following?

If you remove a provisioned switch from the switch stack, the configuration associated with the removed stack member remains in the running configuration as provisioned information. To completely remove the configuration, use the no switch stack-member-number provision global configuration command. This would be followed by renumbering the switch in question to switch 1, I.E:

```
(config)#switch 2 renumber 1  
(config)#do wr  
(config)#end
```

Lastly, reload the switch and it should assume the role of switch 1 in an unprovisioned stack.